# Yii highcharts draw semi circle

Tags: yii, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to make a "semi circle" graph like this one : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle

here is my code :

```
$this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget',
        array(
            'options' => array(
                'scripts' => array(
                    'highcharts-more'
                ),
                'chart' => array(
                    'plotBackgroundColor' => null,
                    'plotBorderWidth' => 0,
                    'plotShadow' => false
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'text' => 'Répartition des modes de paiement',
                ),
                'plotOptions' => array(
                    'pie' => array(
                        'dataLabels' => array(
                            'enabled' => true,
                            'distance' => -50,
                            'style' => array(
                                'fontWeight' => 'bold',
                                'color' => 'white',
                                'textShadow' => '0px 1px 2px black',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'startAngle' => "-90",
                        'endAngle' => "90",
                        'center' => array('50%', '50%')
                    ),
                ),
                'series' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'pie',
                        'innerSize' => '50%',
                        'data' => array(
                            array('Jane', 12),
                            array('John', 13),
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'credits' => array('enabled' => false),
            )
        )
    );
```

However my pie is just rendered as a regular pie not a semi circle.
The params

```
'startAngle' => "-90",    
'endAngle' => "90",
```

are supposed to make that happen, but it doesn't seems to work
Whether i keep or remove these 2 lines, my graph is just a regular graph (full circle)

Any idea about what i'm dong wrong here ?
Many thanks for your help !

Comment: What version of highcharts are you using?

Comment: @wergeld I am using  Highcharts JS v3.0.5 (2013-08-23), and [Yii highcharts v 3.0.5] (https://github.com/miloschuman/yii-highcharts/releases/tag/v3.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your code is sending in string values for `startAngle` and `endAngle`. Try this instead:

```
'startAngle' => -90,
'endAngle' => 90,
```

Comment: What does the jscript on the page look like after rendering?

Comment: Slight change to your fiddle to make it show: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/9uVdv/1/

Comment: Yes i just copied and paste the code from the page source in my version. When I compare your code and mine, I don't see the changes.

In my curent version, the chart actually shows up, but it's a full circle, not a semi-circle (in my yii page) - but when fix to load the different js, it shows a semi-circle.
Not sure I understand what's wrong with my Yii code

Comment: Just a lucky guess, but maybe you have old version for Highcharts?